# requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 symfony

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I installed ext-mongodb

> php --ri mongodb | grep version

```
MongoDB extension version => 1.5.1 
libbson bundled version => 1.11.0
libmongoc bundled version => 1.11.0
```

I have an issue with composer when I do composer install

```
- mongodb/mongodb 1.4.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- mongodb/mongodb 1.3.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.4.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- mongodb/mongodb 1.3.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.4.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- mongodb/mongodb 1.3.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.4.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- mongodb/mongodb 1.4.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
```

My php Info (more details)

```
mongodb
MongoDB support enabled
MongoDB extension version   1.5.1
MongoDB extension stability stable
libbson bundled version 1.11.0
libmongoc bundled version   1.11.0
libmongoc SSL   enabled
libmongoc SSL library   Secure Transport
libmongoc crypto    enabled
libmongoc crypto library    Common Crypto
libmongoc crypto system profile disabled
libmongoc SASL  enabled
libmongoc ICU   disabled
libmongoc compression   enabled
libmongoc compression snappy    disabled
libmongoc compression zlib  enabled
```

If I try to install mongodb with composer

`composer require mongodb/mongodb` I have that error

If I use ( and I don't want use this method )

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

I can see

```
    "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.3",
```

But in This way I can't use some functionality, like aggregateCursor

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "aggregateCursor" of class "MongoDB\Collection"
```

or I can't use 
$m = new \MongoClient();

> Attempted to load class "MongoClient" from the global namespace.

For connect to mongoDb I have to use

> new \MongoDB\Client

I Use Symfony, but I don't think that it's relevant

> Composer version 1.6.5 2018-05-04 11:44:5
>
> PHP 7.2.1 (cli) (built: Jan 15 2018 12:20:50) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group

Comment: sounds weird. only thing I can imagine ... is composer using a different php runtime and/or ini / config. but that's from a purely theoretical standpoint, hence no further practical advice ;o/

Answer (score 7):

Following the below steps, it will work.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libsslcommon2-dev
sudo apt-get install php-pear
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Goto `php.ini` file

```
 extension=mongodb.so
```

Answer (score 3):

For Debian based operating system use following command

```
  sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

Comment: Although this potentially a valid solution, we do not know if the author is using a Debian based operating system or Linux at all. Also please edit your post so it explains what the solution is.

Comment: above command for  Debian based operation system for php and mangodb driver